# iOS - Swift : Expand user profile picture in UIView to view profile picture being used

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, popup, expand

I have an app where you can either take a profile picture, or choose from library, but i want one more option where you can see what profile picture you are using and choosing that option would make your profile picture pop out.

```
    public func present(from sourceView: UIView, didSelect image: UIImage?) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        if self.isMediaTypeVideo {
            if let action = self.action(for: .camera, title: "Take Video") {
                alertController.addAction(action)
            }
            if let action = self.action(for: .photoLibrary, title: "Choose video") {
                alertController.addAction(action)
            }
        }
        else {
            if let action = self.action(for: .camera, title: "Take a Picture") {
                alertController.addAction(action)
            }
            if let action = self.action(for: .photoLibrary, title: "Choose a Picture") {
                alertController.addAction(action)
            }
            if let action = self.action(for: ., title: "View Picture") {
                alertController.addAction(action)
            }
        }
```

Here is my code I got how to do the first two options of "taking a picture" and "choosing from library" but how can i get a third option to look an enlarge version of your current profile picture?

what can i put for the last "View Picture" option on self.action(for:__, title: "View Picture"

I have a protocal function called didselect image that shows what image there is.

```
extension UserAccountSettingsViewController: ImagePickerDelegate {
    func didSelect(image: UIImage?) {
        if let image = image {
            self.startImageLoader()
            if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userImageLastUpdated") == "" {
                uploadFile(withImage: image)
            } else {
                removeFile(upload: true, withImage: image)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably present a view controller with the image taking up most of the screen. Maybe ask a question about how to do that if confused?

Comment: So would i need to create a new view controller and call it when the "View picture" is pressed?

Comment: Yes, subclass `UIViewController` something like `FullScreenImageViewController`  where `FullScreenImageViewController` has a large `UIImageView` and in `viewDidLoad` you can populate that image view with the profile pic. Then in your "View Picture" action say `let imageVC = FullScreenImageViewController(); present(imageVC);`